# How to time-enable a raster layer using ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: raster, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a set of raster layers that cover the same place, over different years. I want to display it on my website using the [timeslider](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer.html) so that I can clearly view the changes between rasters over different years. However, the example given by ESRI site is based on featurelayer, and I have a raster layer. How can I make the raster layer time-aware?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have multiple raster layers, you will need to convert them to a single layer that also happens to be time-aware.

Esri Support wrote [a blog post about this](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/06/01/test/) -- back in 2011, but the principles should still work -- and a GIS StackExchange question covers [publication of time-aware datasets as an image service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/how-to-handle-time-based-raster-data-in-the-arcgis-server-js-api). To summarize their workflow:

1. Create a new mosaic dataset or raster catalog. Add the individual rasters in.
2. Add a new field, of type date (e.g. `year`).
3. Populate `year` with values.
4. Enable time on the layer, and publish it as an image service.

The [Esri JavaScript API example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/image_timeimageservice/) will help with implementation, once you've got everything configured and published.